# Spring OAuth2 server cannot refresh token with Resource owner credentials (password) grant flow

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have configured an OAuth2 authorisation server with spring security oauth, using jwt tokens:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

...
    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore() {
        return new JdbcApprovalStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        var jwtTokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(tokenConverter());
        jwtTokenStore.setApprovalStore(approvalStore());
        return jwtTokenStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter() {
        var converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        var keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource(jwtKeyStore), jwtKeyPass.toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwtkey"));
        return converter;
    }

}
```

There is a client that has `password` and `refresh_token` grants. I can get access and refresh tokens with the following request:

```
curl --request POST \
   --url 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&scope=read' \
  --header 'authorization: Basic <xxxxxxx>' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxx'
```

Response:

```
{
    "access_token": "<long access token>",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "<long refresh token>",
    "expires_in": 599,
    "scope": "read",
    "subject": "xxx",
    "jti": "xxx"
}
```

However, when I try to refresh the token, I get an error `Invalid refresh token`. Further debugging into Spring codes I see that on the first request, it doesn't insert a row into `oauth_approvals` table. And on the second request (refreshing the token) it thinks that the user has not approved the scope (although I have `autoapprove=true`).

This is not the case with `implicit` or `authorization_code` grant flow: in those cases it does insert a row into `oauth_approvals` table, and the token is refreshed successfully.

Is this a bug in Spring OAuth or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more into Spring's codes, I came to conclusion that this is indeed a bug there. So I extended `JdbcApprovalStore` and used that one instead. Here is pseudo-code

```
public class JdbcApprovalStoreAutoApprove extends JdbcApprovalStore {
    ...
    @Override
    public List<Approval> getApprovals(String userName, String clientId) {
        if (client has auto approved scopes) {
            return those scopes;
        }
        return super.getApprovals(userName, clientId);
    }
```

Comment: You should have reported that bug to the Spring Security team to have it validated and fixed.